# Could not load definitions from resource when using ant task

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I'm using ant-contrib in my build script

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="ant/ant-contrib-0.6.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

It works. But when I'm calling some target in this script from another ant file using `ant` task, I'm getting the error.

```
<ant antfile="build.xml" target="make" dir="${client.project.location}/ant"/>
```

Please, help me to fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code we can see

```
 <classpath>
    <pathelement location="ant/ant-contrib-0.6.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

1. You need to give path **location="/home/[some

   path]/ant-contrib-0.6.jar"**
2. you can do one more thing,you need to copy your ant-contrib-0.6.jar
   into **ANT_HOME/lib** folder and remove your  tag completely from you code.
   **Note:** Second option is always better.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `usenativebasedir="true"` when calling ant task